# How can I access and erase every 2nd last element from a multiset?

Tags: c++, multiset

I was lately trying to access every 2nd last element from a multiset container. Here I want to first print every 2nd last element from the container then erase it from the container. This process continues until the size of the container reaches to 1.

My so far approach for this process is given bellow-

```
int n;cin>>n;
multiset<int>st;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    int x;cin>>x;st.insert(x);
}
while(st.size()!=1)
{
    auto it=st.rbegin();
    prev(it,1);
    cout<<*it<<" ";
    st.erase(*it);
}
```

Here, my expected results for the given case is-

```
6
0 0 1 0 1 1
```

ans- `1 1 0 0 0`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer of the question .Here as I am using multiset I accidently erasing all copies of (*it).So I just need to find the value first then erase from the set.

> st.erase(find(*it))